# how to get Cursor Invisbile or change focus in out of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want cursor to be active only inside `div` and invisible outside of this `div`. How to do this?

I am using `jQuery` drag and drop functionality. When I drag its move all over the browser. I need to fix some particular height and width drag works only the particular fixed size how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Hello roy,Welocome to StackOverflow and check my answer,hope it will be helped to you,and keep it mind  Quintin Balsdon said thing :)
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Set `cursor:none` to `body, html` and `cursor: default` on your `div`

```css
body,html{
  cursor: none;
  }
#cursor{
  cursor: default;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="cursor">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution would be the following:

css

```
div {cursor: auto }

* { cursor: none; }
```

**However**, how would the user find the div if they cannot see the pointer???

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  cursor: none;
}

div {
  cursor: auto;
}
```

should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The `CSS` property that can be used is:

```
element.style {
   cursor: none;   
}
```

Here is sample code

```css
.nocursor {
      cursor: none;
      
      padding: 2em;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nocursor">
      When you mouse hover in div class,cursor will be hide
</div>
```